# Is there a site for City Planning and/or Road Traffic Management?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

The question I'm looking to pose is:

> Our state Dept of Transportation are considering adding some
>   [Rectangular Rapid Flashing
>   Beacons](http://pedbikesafe.org/PEDSAFE/countermeasures_detail.cfm?CM_NUM=54)
>   (RRFB) along a state road that passes through our neighborhood.
>
> The engineer says that these "don't sync with other signals" along
>   the route and could disrupt the flow of traffic.
>
> We (the residents) are wondering why we can't have RRFBs that DO sync
>   with other signals, notifying pedestrians of how long until the beacon
>   will next activate.

Is there a site which would make sense for that one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet would be our [Engineering site](https://engineering.stackexchange.com). They have a few tags about [highway*], [traffic*], [roads*], and civil engineering.